# xml file stored on database in Windows and loaded/filled on Unix server with JasperReport

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports

I have a web aplication deployed into a linux server. I have a xml with line breaks stored in database, and the insert script sql was generate in Windows. I generate the dynamic file into memory using

```
    String templateDDBB = 'String_loaded_from_DataBase';
    InputStream templateStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( templateDDBB.getBytes( Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()) ) );

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    // compile the JRXML file
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(xmlTemplateStream);
    // We are using an empty datasource because datasource is not required.
    JREmptyDataSource dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource();

    // Fill the report with data
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);

    if(reportType.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")){
        baos = generatePdfOutput(jasperPrint);
    }

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=somefile.pdf");
    baos.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
```

When I try download the file I recive a 0 bytes file, because anything fail.

I have checked that it is due to the differences in the format of the **line breaks between linux(\n) and windows(\r\n)**.

**How i can generate the final XML file independently of the operating system (Windows/Unix)?**

any trick? pre-format? pre-proccess string? andything that work in both (Windows/ Unix)?

Comment: "because anything fail." ?? you need to use try, catch, log the message and post stacktrace.

Comment: dude... the code snniper not is all my code.... I have try..catch, but the code does not produce a error... I can download the file correctly with a 200 HTTP response, but the file weight 0 bytes....I know that the problem has relation with file codification ... but this dont procuce a exception.....In Windows Work correctly. In linux not.

Comment: Check if the jasperPrint  has pages or is empty, check ByteArrayOutputStream baos stream actually is 0, you need to narrow down where the problem can be... if jasper print is empty this could mean a problem with attribute whenNoDataType (since you are using empty datasource). To me there is no other trick then debugging to find exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the font "Times New Roman", in Linux doesn`t exists and the generation from jasper failed. there are 2 possible solutions: install fonts on Server (Unix) or change font into template for use other free font.